Chrome extension, adding instance to global scope such as window on Instagram.com seems futile
So, I am trying to script some stuff against instagram, but I've noticed that Instagram is somehow able to clear access to any variable or instance put on window.aaa, or window.document.aaa or window.document.documentElement.aaa or window.addEventEventListener.aaa will eventually all disappear.
When I set any of these properties, I am able to verify that:
a) things execute where I set things
b) things are set on the property
However, some vodoo magic is happening and I've first encountered it on Instagram, and one Bank website.
Instances, wherever they are set on, will all become inaccessible eventually.
My first question is, how do they pull it off? Is there some kind of listener they are utilizing to ensure things not set by them somehow is cleared.
Second question is, are there any known ways around this?
You can easily try this by installing Custom Javascript Extension and enable jquery for Instagram.com but it will not become available on the window object.

Sounds like you're not doing it in the MAIN world.
